# AutoIt input controls ignored by game

Tags: bots, autoit, sendinput

I'm trying to send input from an AutoIt script to a game. I used Spy++ and when I press <kbd>W</kbd> it receives:

[image: messages received by the game image]

But when I use `Send("w")` or any other method that simulates input (`ControlSend()`, `MouseClick()`, `ControlClick()`) it receives nothing. I also tried `SendMessage`, `PostMessage` and `SendInput` in C#.

I tried it on Notepad and Chrome and that worked just fine. Could the developers block these methods so the game doesn't receive the events?

Comment: `blocking` might be the wrong word. Some games (and obviously `Spy++` too) implement an own keyboard scanning. So there is no entry point for `send` etc.

Comment: I assumed that if Spy++ shows the messages received by the process when I use the keyboard, it means that the process uses the input received from PostMessage/ SendMessage/ SendInput etc. 

It makes sense anyway, that even if the process receives these messages, they might actually be ignored and it uses some sort of keyboard scanning. 

I still don't understand why Spy++ doesn't pick up the messages when I send controls from AutoIt, but it does pick them up when I send them to Notepad/ Chrome.

Comment: When Spy++ doesn't pick up messages, maybe there indeed is no communication (which nees a sender *and*  a receiver - no receiver, no communication, no matter how much the sender is sending).

Comment: Did you try changing the SendKeyDownDelay and SendKeyDelay options from their defaults of 5ms? Often this is too short for games. Experiment with larger values like 200+.